# Maths for deeply understanding backpropgation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, calculus

I have been trying to develop a deeper understanding of Neural Networks so I can understand the libraries such as tensorflow and others. I have had good success with pereceptron models, and have a good enough understanding of linear algebra, and the other mechanics behind the networks as well.

But now as I am getting into multi-layer Perceptrons. The concept of backpropogation is just above me. I have little to no understanding of basic calculus concepts. (I will only start taking pre-calc/Calculus1 next year.) So I wish to start studying up on the concepts now.

I know I need to have a good understanding of derivatives, the chain rule, and gradient descent. But what all concepts of calculus do I need to understand in order better under stand the pseudo code, lectures I have been reading up on.

I have watched 3blue1brown's and The Coding Train's neural network series, but the concepts for backpropogation are a little over my head. Additionally, any resources for learning would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi: This looks pretty good at a glance. https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/12/06/backpropagation-for-dummies/ . Note that I don't think it's a matter of understanding more math as long as you understand calculus and leibniz rule. It's more a matter of understanding WHY the algorithm works. That's a different issue from understanding the math.

Comment: you need to understand the gradient. the concept is not deep at all. don't go gung ho on calculus. just get the idea of a rate of change of multivariate function and why is it zero at the bottom

Comment: I forgot to include that you do need understanding of what the  gradient is also. Thanks Aksakal for pointing that out.

Comment: This is great, thanks! So what I am getting from this is I don't need to have a solid understanding of calculus, but just an understanding of gradient and the rate of change? If so, then where does the chain rule come into play, I have heard in mentioned a lot in my studies.

Comment: it's good to know calculus and linear algebra, but not necessary to be useful and productive in implementing or using deep learning tools. i just dont want you to feel overwhelmed trying to bite more than you can chew at first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of analysis/calculus I don't believe you need anything beyond the chain rule (but for functions on vectors) to understand how weights are updated. As an aside, modern deep networks employ a lot of specialized structures (e.g. convolutional layers) which makes it difficult to figure out the exact update equations by hand - so that's why libraries such as tensorflow and pytorch use automatic differentiation. [This](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume18/17-468/17-468.pdf) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

#### Backpropagation

Backpropagation is the heart of every neural network. Firstly, we need to make a distinction between backpropagation and optimizers.

Backpropagation is for calculating the gradients efficiently, while optimizers is for training the neural network, using the gradients computed with backpropagation. In short, all backpropagation does for us is compute the gradients. Nothing more.

[image]
*[Pic Credits](https://mlfromscratch.com/neural-networks-explained/#/)*

We always start from the output layer and propagate backwards, updating weights and biases for each layer.

The idea is simple: adjust the weights and biases throughout the network, so that we get the desired output in the output layer. Say we wanted the output neuron to be 1.0, then we would need to nudge the weights and biases so that we get an output closer to 1.0.

We can only change the weights and biases, but activations are direct calculations of those weights and biases, which means we indirectly can adjust every part of the neural network, to get the desired output — except for the input layer, since that is the dataset that you input.

#### The backpropagation algorithm

The backpropagation equations provide us with a way of computing the gradient of the cost function. Let's explicitly write this out in the form of an algorithm:

**1. Input $x$:** Set the corresponding activation $a^{1}$ for the input layer.

**2. Feedforward:** For each $l = 2, 3, \ldots, L$ compute

$z^{l} = w^l a^{l-1}+b^l$ and $a^{l} = \sigma(z^{l})$

**3. Output error $\delta^L$:** Compute the vector $\delta^{L}
  = \nabla_a C \odot \sigma'(z^L)$.

**4. Backpropagate the error:** For each $l = L-1, L-2,
  \ldots, 2$
compute

$\delta^{l} = ((w^{l+1})^T \delta^{l+1}) \odot
  \sigma'(z^{l})$.

**5. Output:** The gradient of the cost function is given by

$\frac{\partial C}{\partial w^l_{jk}} = a^{l-1}_k \delta^l_j$ and $\frac{\partial C}{\partial b^l_j} = \delta^l_j$.

Examining the algorithm you can see why it's called backpropagation. We compute the error vectors $\delta^l$ backward, starting from the final layer. It may seem peculiar that we're going through the network backward. But if you think about the proof of backpropagation, the backward movement is a consequence of the fact that the cost is a function of outputs from the network. To understand how the cost varies with earlier weights and biases we need to repeatedly apply the chain rule, working backward through the layers to obtain usable expressions.

Below are the resources which would help you to Understand Backpropagation

> **[How might we measure the change in the cost function in relation to a specific weight, bias or activation?](https://mlfromscratch.com/neural-networks-explained/#backpropagation)**
>
> **[Understanding Backpropagation Algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-backpropagation-algorithm-7bb3aa2f95fd)**
>
> **[Backpropagation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/backpropagation/)**
>
> **[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)**

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but the notation used in steps 3-5 of your diagram is a little beyond me. Is there any way you could provide a key or maybe elaborate more on the concepts?

Comment: For a complete walkthrough of the algorithm and the deep math visit  [Link](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html)